# How add new values in drop-down list using plugin "selectory" jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, plugins

I need some help. How can I  add new values in code to the list if I use a plugin from jquery. I wrote this code, but the list is empty, although the values are passed to the view. This is probably due to the fact that I am referring to the id of the div tag, but the plugin did not work differently. Help please

```
<html>
<main>
<form action="#">
<div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-sm-4" id="example-2"> </div>
</form>
</main>       
<script>
            $('#example-2').selectivity({
                items: ['Amsterdam', 'Antwerp'],
                multiple: true,
                placeholder: 'Type to search a city'
            });

            function addOption() {

                var ul = document.getElementById("#example-2");
                for (var item in @ViewBag.List)
                {
                    
                    var value = item;
                }
               
                var newOption = new Option(value, value);
                ul.options[ul.options.length] = newOption;
            }
</script>
</html>
```

[result of code from answer 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhiSV.png)

Comment: You can easily add options using the libraries' `add()` method - see their [documentation](https://arendjr.github.io/selectivity/#methods). The bigger issue you have is outputting the `@Viewbag.List` from C# to your JS. I'd suggest outputting it from the server as JSON and parsing that in your JS.

Comment: I read the documentation, thank you. But the misunderstanding remained. If I want to send a list from the server, the elements of the list and its length are not known to me in advance. How do I add list items to the drop-down list? My application is on asp.net MVC. Could you help me and give a small example?

Comment: I added an answer showing some demo code below.

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation of the selectivity library](https://arendjr.github.io/selectivity/#methods) covers how to add new options to the dropdown.

The main issue you have is that the output from `@ViewBag.List` won't be in a format that JS can understand. I would suggest formatting it as JSON before outputting it to the page, then the JS can access this as a standard object, though which you can loop.

```js
// initialisation
$('#example-2').selectivity({
  items: ['Amsterdam', 'Antwerp'],
  multiple: true,
  placeholder: 'Type to search a city'
});

// add options, somewhere else in your codebase...
const $list = $('#example-2')
const options = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.List));
options.forEach((option, i) => {
  $list.selectivity('add', { id: i, text: option })
});
```

Note that for this to work the JS code which reads from the `ViewBag` needs to be placed somewhere the C# code will be executed, ie. in a .cshtml file, *not* in a .js file.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help, but I have a compilation error after "forEach": CS1977: Cannot use a lambda expression as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation. ViewBag.List is list of strings

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. The output of the ViewBag in C# and the forEach in JS need to be separated, so there's not confusion over which language we need to loop in :) I also updated the `add` logic to work with a list of strings.

Comment: I used your code. Now the data from the ViewBag is displayed as already selected data (I attach a screenshot at the end of the question). Is it possible to add data directly to the list so that the user can select them? I tried to use the "data" method, too, not the same effect.

Comment: It appears not from the documentation linked above. If that's your goal I would suggest upgrading to a newer library which has this feature and is still actively maintained, such as Chosen.

Comment: What do you mean by "Chosen"?

Comment: https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/